# Path for simulator build

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How do we find the location of the directory where we put simulator build? In my system the path is `Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications`. What would be the path on someone else's system?

Comment: By *simulator build* do you mean the output of Xcode after it builds the app, or the binary that is executed inside the simulator?

Comment: Binaries that is executed inside the simulator.

Answer (score 8):

You can look for a folder called **Derived Data** in the **Projects** tab in **Organizer**. Xcode includes index, build output and logs there. So you can find there the built binary for the Simulator and for iOS devices. You can open this folder by right clicking on the device build and selecting **Show in Finder**.

The folder you mentioned is the folder where Xcode puts the binaries that it passes to the simulator when you launch your app there. It is usually in the same location.

Answer (score 5):

$user$/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications.
Or get the path using the line:

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
```

This line returns you the path to the Documents folder **in** your app.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Xcode Command to find it
just pause your project and type `po NSHomeDirectory()` like below picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSHomeDirectory());
```

or

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents"];
```

Answer (score 0):

right click on the finish product and say "show in finder"

Comment: You just need to move a folder up and you'll see the `XXXX-iphonesimulator` where you'll have the simulator build @picciano.