# How can I get a path relative to the project directory?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

So I am working on a swift project managed by Swift Package Manager.  For some of my tests I would like to load files from the directory `${PACKAGE_ROOT}/testData`

The thing is, if I run the tests via the command line (i.e. `$ swift test` then I can get the root using the current directory path: `FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath`.  However, I would like to use the XCode test runner to take advantage of the debugger, and when run from the test runner, the `currentDirectoryPath` is in `DerivedData`.

Is there a good way to get a path relative to the test project directory at runtime?  A few other critical things here:

1. I want the tests to pass *regardless* of the project location.  I.e. if someone clones the project to an arbitrary location, the tests should run identically.  Therefore explicitly setting the complete path to the project is out.
2. I want to avoid something which requires modification of the generated XCode project, because these changes will not be stable if the project needs to be re-generated from the package.  I.e. if a new dependency or target is added.

Comment: I do not have much experience with the Swift package manager, but you might use the `#file` compiler directive, which becomes the full source file name.

Comment: Thanks - I think I can make this work for me.

Comment: You can see there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404422/path-for-simulator-build/50507607#50507607